# C# Windows Service with GUI

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am creating a task scheduler that needs to be running even when the user is logged off. From what I've read, a windows service is best for this.

Obviously it also needs a GUI for the user to actually schedule tasks.

I don't think windows services can have a GUI, what is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write two programs.

The first is the UI for managing the data - adding & removing schedules etc.

The second is the Windows service that just reads the data and acts on it.

You'll need a database or configuration file that both programs can read and write to, so you'll need to have some form of data locking to prevent issues if both the service and GUI are trying to update the data at the same time.

The "database" doesn't have to be a full blown relational database like SQL or oracle. It would probably be enough to be a configuration file that the GUI writes and the service reads. The storage method you choose depends on the volume and complexity of the data you need to store.

Comment: The tasks will be machine specific, you think having a column "machine name" which identifies which tasks are for which machine will do the job?

Comment: @TomCarroll - probably, but only if you really need to. If it's machine specific  you can have the database on each machine. Your installer will install the GUI, the service and the database on each machine.

Comment: db is probably overkill if OP only needs 1-2 tasks

Comment: @Steve - possibly. I originally wrote "need a database (even if it's only a text file)", but thought that would possible confuse matters.

Comment: @ChrisF good idea I was imagining using the database on the local server

Comment: @Steve there will probably be no more than 10 tasks per machine

Comment: @TomCarroll a text file should be enough in this case. no need to over engineer it to make it fancy imo

Answer (score 0):

You can create scheduled task using "Task Scheduler" utility in Windows. You can specify the frequency, executable etc details in the "Task Scheduler".